# django. при создании супер-пользователя в кастомной модели вылезает ошибка

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

Трейсбек при создании супер-пользователя:

```
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/mnt/e/Work/WEB/django/72tob/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/mnt/e/Work/WEB/django/72tob/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/mnt/e/Work/WEB/django/72tob/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/mnt/e/Work/WEB/django/72tob/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 59, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/mnt/e/Work/WEB/django/72tob/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/mnt/e/Work/WEB/django/72tob/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 179, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
TypeError: create_superuser() got an unexpected keyword argument
```

[model.py]

```
from time import timezone
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin

class TemporaryBanIp(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "TemporaryBanIp"

    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField("IP адрес")
    attempts = models.IntegerField("Неудачных попыток", default=0)
    time_unblock = models.DateTimeField("Время разблокировки", blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField("Статус блокировки", default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ip_address


class TemporaryBanIpAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('ip_address', 'status', 'attempts', 'time_unblock')
    search_fields = ('ip_address',)


class AuthUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, first_name, last_name, patronymic,
                    birth_day, inn_id, passport_s, passport_n, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=AuthUserManager.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            last_name=last_name,
            first_name=first_name,
            patronymic=patronymic,
            birth_day=birth_day,
            inn_id=inn_id,
            passport_s=passport_s,
            passport_n=passport_n,
        )

        user.is_admin = True
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, patronymic,
                    birth_day, inn_id, passport_s, passport_n, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=email,
            password=password,
            last_name=last_name,
            first_name=first_name,
            patronymic=patronymic,
            birth_day=birth_day,
            inn_id=inn_id,
            passport_s=passport_s,
            passport_n=passport_n,
        )

        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

class AuthUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    patronymic = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    birth_day = models.DateTimeField()

    inn_id = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    passport_n = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
    passport_s = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = AuthUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['last_name', 'first_name', 'patronymic', 'email', 'birth_day', 'inn_id', 'passport_s', 'passport_n']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return u'%s %s %s' % (self.first_name, self.patronymic, self.last_name)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return u'%s' % self.first_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    return True

@property
def is_staff(self):
    return self.is_admin

# @property
# def is_superuser(self):
#     return self.is_superuser
```

[admin.py]

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField
# from simplemathcaptcha.fields import MathCaptchaField

from .models import AuthUser


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
        password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password',
            widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Password'}))

        password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation',
            widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'confirm password'}))
        # captcha = MathCaptchaField()

        class Meta:
            model = AuthUser
            fields = ('last_name', 'first_name', 'patronymic', 'username', 'email', 'birth_day', 'inn_id', 'passport_s', 'passport_n')

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(UserCreationForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
            self.fields['birth_day'].widget.attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Date of birth'}
            self.fields['email'].widget.attrs={'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Email'}

        def clean_password2(self):
            password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
            if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords don\'t match')

            return password2

        def save(self, commit=True):
            user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
            user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
            if commit:
                user.save()

            return user


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    # The forms to add and change user instances
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    list_display = ('email', 'birth_day', 'is_admin')
    list_filter = ('is_admin',)

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': ('last_name', 'first_name', 'patronymic', 'username', 'email', 'birth_day', 'inn_id', 'passport_s', 'passport_n')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_admin',)}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'birth_day', 'password1', 'password2', )} # ,'captcha',
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('username',)
    ordering = ('username',)
    filter_horizontal = ()

admin.site.register(AuthUser, UserAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(Group)
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Сделайте `superuser.def create_user(self, **kwargs): print(kwargs)` чтобы увидеть какие аргументы пришли

Comment: @AndrioSkur Это вписать в консоль или модуль?

Comment: В модуле. Надо заменить `create_superuser(self, email, first_name, last_name, patronymic,
                    birth_day, inn_id, passport_s, passport_n, password=None)` в `model.py` на `def create_user(self, **kwargs): print(kwargs)`

Comment: @AndrioSkur Сделал, как сказали (def create_superuser(self, **kwargs): print(kwargs). Выхлоп: `{'passport_s': 1234, 'last_name': 'las', 'patronymic': 'p', 'inn_id': 1234, 'first_name': 'f', 'passport_n': 12345678, 'birth_day': datetime.datetime(1996, 7, 1, 0, 0)}
Superuser created successfully.`

Comment: В `create_superuser` уберите строку `password=password` .